# Remove the content entry from TOC in scrbook class, existing solutions did not work

Tags: tableofcontents

The TOC is having the first entry as "Contents", that I like to remove. I searched for the solutions( That are quite old, and does not work anymore) that says either to use **\tableofcontents***  or use an environment

```
\begin{KeepFromToc}
  \tableofcontents
\end{KeepFromToc}
```

Which is not recognized by my class file ( non memoir class)
The MWC is given below

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside,chapterprefix=TRUE]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[pass,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage[notindex]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{makeidx} 


\makeindex

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\setcounter{page}{1}
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\listoffigures
%\KOMAoptions{open=right}
\include{acronyms}
\include{ACK}
\include{Publications Related to Thesis}
\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
\backmatter
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The output I currently getting--
[image: TOC Output]

Comment: Whoever has downgraded the question,  please provide a link or working solution,  as I have already mentioned that existing solutions aren't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after so many solutions finally **\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}** solved the problem.